# Função com laço de repetição em python

Tags: python

Olá,

Estou tentando usar uma função para pegar a lista completa de containers independente do status, "docker ps -a".
Quando uso o código fora da função, ele funciona.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando uso o mesmo código por dentro da função, ele só me retorna o primeiro elemento da lista.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que isso acontece ?

Comment: **Fabiano** não utilize imagem, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/340694/edit) a pergunta e coloque o código, fazendo assim você ajuda quem for te ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso acontece porque um `return` sempre vai ser um final de uma função.

Você pode ter infinitos `return`, no primeiro que tocar sua função irá ser finalizada e vai retornar o objeto que o return está apontando.

Exemplo:

Função que imprime uma lista.

Em ambos os casos eles irão receber como entrada:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Abaixo dois casos, sendo que o ultimo é o que você está utilizando.

```
def printar(n):
    for x in n:
        print(x)
```

Esse seria um esqueleto perfeito para o seu código. Pois o resultado seria:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Entretanto, o que você está tentando fazer é:

```
def printar(n):
    for x in n:
        return(x)
```

Que o resultado seria:

```
1
```